# Can I change TextView link text after using Linkify?

Tags: android, linkify

Is is possible to change TextView text after using Linkify to create links? I have something where I want the url to have two fields, a name and id, but then I just want the text to display the name.

So I start off with a textview with text that includes both name and id, and linkify to create the appropriate links with both fields. But for the display, I don't want to show the id.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's kind of a pain but yes. So Linkify basically does a few things. First it scans the contents of the textview for strings that match that of a url. Next it creates UrlSpan's and ForegroundColorSpan's for those sections that match it. Then it sets the MovementMethod of the TextView.

The important part here are the UrlSpan's. If you take your TextView and call getText(), notice it returns a CharSequence. It's most likely some sort of Spanned. From the Spanned you can ask, getSpans() and specifcally the UrlSpans. Once you know all those spans you can than loop through the list and find and replace the old span objects with your new span objects.

```
mTextView.setText(someString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
if(Linkify.addLinks(mTextView, Linkify.ALL)) {
 //You can use a SpannableStringBuilder here if you are going to
 // manipulate the displayable text too. However if not this should be fine.
 Spannable spannable = (Spannable) mTextView.getText();
 // Now we go through all the urls that were setup and recreate them with
 // with the custom data on the url.
 URLSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length, URLSpan.class);
 for (URLSpan span : spans) {
   // If you do manipulate the displayable text, like by removing the id
   // from it or what not, be sure to keep track of the start and ends
   // because they will obviously change.
   // In which case you may have to update the ForegroundColorSpan's as well
   // depending on the flags used
   int start = spannable.getSpanStart(span);
   int end = spannable.getSpanEnd(span);
   int flags = spannable.getSpanFlags(span);
   spannable.removeSpan(span);
   // Create your new real url with the parameter you want on it.
   URLSpan myUrlSpan = new URLSpan(Uri.parse(span.getUrl).addQueryParam("foo", "bar");
   spannable.setSpan(myUrlSpan, start, end, flags);
 }
 mTextView.setText(spannable);
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Linkify is just a nice tool to setup the correct Spans. Spans just get interpreted when rendering text.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that's very helpful.  I didn't know what goes on "behind the scenes" when you use linkify.

Comment: I concur, it was very helpful. I wasn't paying attention and copied your `int flags = spannable.getSpanEnd(span);` and that wrecked havoc as it was setting essentially random flags. I submitted an edit for review; hopefully no one else fell into the same pit hole... it was dark :).

Comment: The question asks how to modify the content of the TextView after it applying linkify. Where in this code are you replacing the actual text without changing the referenced URL? If you replace the span, aren't you replacing the URL and the text at the same time?

Comment: So in this example, I say don't change the text. Think of the text as the display as you want it. So set it to that, no need to manipulate the text buffer after it's been set. The functionality should be in the UrlSpan's url. Spans and the actual text are independent. Spans are just arbitrary objects that reference a range of characters in a buffer. So you can change them independently of the actual buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Greg's answer doesn't really answer the original question. But it does contain some insight as to where to start. Here's a function that you can use. It assumes that you have [Linkified](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) your textview prior to this call. It's in Kotlin, but you can get the gist of it if you are using Java.

In short, it builds a new Spannable with your new text. During the build, it copies over the url/flags of the URLSpans that the Linkify call created previously.

```kt
fun TextView.replaceLinkedText(pattern: String) { // whatever pattern you used to Linkify textview
    if(this.text !is Spannable) return // no need to process since there are no URLSpans
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(this.text)
    val linkifiedText = SpannableStringBuilder()
    var cursorPos = 0
    val spannable = this.text as Spannable
    while (matcher.find()) {
        linkifiedText.append(this.text.subSequence(cursorPos, matcher.start()))
        cursorPos = matcher.end()
        val span = spannable.getSpans(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), URLSpan::class.java).first()
        val spanFlags = spannable.getSpanFlags(span)
        val tag = matcher.group(2) // whatever you want to display
        linkifiedText.append(tag) 
        linkifiedText.setSpan(URLSpan(span.url), linkifiedText.length - tag.length, linkifiedText.length, spanFlags)
    }
    this.text = linkifiedText
}
```