# How to prevent crashing for map links if maps not installed

Tags: android

I have a TextView that has an address that is auto-linked such that clicking on it will open the address in maps or other app (e.g. Google Earth). That works fine when you have a mapping application installed. The first time I tried it on an emulator clicking the link crashed the app because it could not find any Activity to handle the link.

What's the best way to intercept the link and check if a suitable handler is available so that if not I can pop up a nice notice offering to take them to the play store to install Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

This is not just a question of whether a mapping application is installed -- with restricted profiles in Android 4.3+, the mapping application may be installed but unavailable to the current user.

Right now, [until they fix `URLSpan`](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58438), you will need to bulk-replace the `URLSpan` instances with your own subclass, as is described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945716/115145). Your subclass could just override `onClick(View)` and chain to the superclass inside of an `ActivityNotFoundException` `try`/`catch` block, where you then do something in that circumstance.

If you are manually running `Linkify`, you can fix things up after `Linkify` has done its work. If you are using `android:autoLink`, I *think* you can fix things up after your `setText()` call, but it is possible it will need to be a bit later, as I forget exactly when `TextView` does its internal `Linkify` call.